# My Ipad 2 does not want to charge: how should i fix it?

Tags: ios, ipad, charger

My Ipad is very old but still works well, the only thing it does not work is *charging issue*. The original charger was damaged, and I have replaced it with a accessory for it. Later on, when I want to charge, instead of charging it does the opposite of charging while having plugged in. And this is really weird, because before it did not happebed this.

So, how should I deal with *charging mal function*? I have tried to reboot, but it did not worked. I have tried to look for the answer but its unclear, because it is not the answer I was looking for..

Comment: It's a physical issue - either you need a new battery, a new lightning port, or a new logic board.

Comment: @Allan Ok, thanx for your answer. I'll see what I can do about it. "New lightning port"?! What is that?

Comment: The port on the iPad where you connect the charger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague but we can make a few suggestions based on what it *could be.*

1. Replace the charger and cable with a new charger and cable. If the charger went bad (and a cable could masquerade as a bad charger) replacing it (or testing it) with a new one of each should narrow down the problem.
2. I don't know what "the opposite of charging" means. But if the iPad powers off when you unplug it I would think item one above isn't gonna help as the charger/cable are providing power to the iPad. That might indicate a bad/worn out battery.

Note that the indication that it might be other than the battery (replace the lightning port or logic board) is possible.

Honestly I would take it to a trusted independent service center and see what they say.